# remove() on img with ng-src, border remains?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have some ng-repeated images.

```
<img ng-src="{{::data.image}}" />
```

css:

```
.thumbnailImage {
  width: auto;
  max-width: 20px;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid lightslategrey;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-color: white; /* in case of png */
  }
```

Some of {{data.image}} is null. I want to remove those.

```
<img ng-src="{{::data.image}}" onerror="this.remove()" />
```

However when i do this the 1px border i have on the images still remains?

before this i had a ng-if statement (ng-src != null), but i found out that was too expensive in angular watchers.

https://jsfiddle.net/8ykrkc3c/

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<div ng-if="data.image">
   <img  ng-src="{{::data.image}}"  />
</div>
```

**Edit:**

you can use custome dirctive for this.

```js
angular.module("app", [])
  .controller("MainCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.value = "https://www.google.co.in/images/srpr/logo11w.png";
  //  $scope.value = "null";
  })
  .directive('custSrc', function() {
    return {
      restrict: "A",
      scope: {
        value: "=custSrc"
      },
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          if(scope.value == 'null')
             element.parent().addClass('hide'); 
          else
            element.attr('src', scope.value);
        
        console.log(element);

      }
    };
  });
```

```css
.hide{
  display:none;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
 <div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
   <img  cust-src="value" />
 </div>
```

Comment: with that amount of data i have, a ng-if is gonna be expensive in watchers.

Comment: so use custome directive for this.

Comment: @AndersPedersen You could also one time bind it, if the src's won't change

Answer (score 1):

Your onerror handler is incorrect. Note, that it's no longer Angular attribute and hence you can't use [angular.element.prototype.remove](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) method. Instead you need to go with good old native DOM methods, in your case [removeChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild):

```
<img class="asd" ng-src="{{::data.image}}" onerror="this.parentNode.removeChild(this)" />
```

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/8ykrkc3c/2/

Comment: Your demo uses `ng-src` instead of `src`. Because there is no Angular in your demo `ng-src` doesn't mean and do anything, as the result there is no `src` attribute. And onload/onerror events are not fired for img element in case if there is no src.