# What is the shortest way to call a scope function directly within a DOM event handler

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have this scope function

```
$scope.foo = function() {
   console.log('foo')
}
```

What is the shortest way of calling it in a DOM event handler?

```
<img src='foo.jpg' onError="???">
```

Please note that the code is a sample. I don't need to know how to handle failing images.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16349578/angular-directive-for-a-fallback-image

Comment: see this anwer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36834527/remove-on-img-with-ng-src-border-remains/36834559#36834559

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solves the issue:

```
<img src='foo.jpg' onError="angular.element(this).scope().foo()">
```

Comment: Yes it does the job but has bad affects with scope nesting because of this context.You may want to select the right element for right scope variable. Please see http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/3314/ for better understanding.

Comment: It will automatically select the right controller if you use `this`

Comment: It's selects the right controller ,but it may not be the controller you would be expecting to get selected.please see the jsfiddle for better explanation.

Comment: `angular.element(this).scope()` always selects the right scope even when there are child scopes. Please observe the fiddle carefully.

Answer (score -1):

Please see following code.Using this approach scope function can be called without any nested scoping issue.

```
 <div id="myctrl" ng-controller="MyCtrl">

     <div ng-controller="DemoCtrl">
       <img src='foo.jpg'onError="angular.element(document.getElementById('myctrl')).scope().foo()">
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: This is not what I asked. Please read the question well. Please use comments for commentary.

Comment: You mentioned code is just a sample. So I answered in generic manner.

Comment: Correction its {{foo()}}

Comment: that doesn't work. Please test your code before publishing.